# Neighbouring Group Participation of Aldehyde group

Tags: organic-chemistry, nucleophilic-substitution

Does the aldehyde group -CHO give neighbouring group participation? For example in the following compound:

[image: compound]

Why or why not will the formyl group show neighboring group participation? Although I have never seen an example of a -CHO group showing SN-NGP, it does seem feasible due to the lone pair of O, but I am not sure if it occurs or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

If NGP occurs, the resultant ring would be highly unstable and strained due to Oxygen also doubly bonded to a Carbon.